# jQuery focus after submit on last input field edited

Tags: jquery, html

On jQuery keyup on two IDs a function is executed.

```
$('#supplier_name').keyup(function(){
    clearTimeout(typingTimer);
    if ($('#supplier_name').val) {
        typingTimer = setTimeout(doneTyping, doneTypingInterval);
    }
    $.cookie("inputFocus", "#supplier_name"); 
});
```

After this the form is submitted. I want to do jQuery .focus on the ID which led the keyup function to execute.

So if I entered text into #supplier_name after form submit I want the focus to be on that. Vice versa with #aircraft_type.

EDIT: I am trying to do this via cookies however it doesn't seem to be working.

How do I do this with the following jQuery code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#state").change(function () {
    this.form.submit();
})
$.cookie("inputFocus").focus();
$("#supplier_name").val($("#supplier_name").val());
$("#aircraft_type").val($("#aircraft_type").val());
var typingTimer;                
var doneTypingInterval = 800;  

$('#supplier_name').keyup(function(){
    clearTimeout(typingTimer);
    if ($('#supplier_name').val) {
        typingTimer = setTimeout(doneTyping, doneTypingInterval);
    }
    $.cookie("inputFocus", "#supplier_name"); 
});

$('#aircraft_type').keyup(function(){
    clearTimeout(typingTimer);
    if ($('#aircraft_type').val) {
        typingTimer = setTimeout(doneTyping, doneTypingInterval);
    }
    $.cookie("inputFocus", "#aircraft_type"); });

function doneTyping () {
    $("form").submit();
}

});
</script>
```

Comment: I think you meant `$('#supplier_name, #aircraft_type').val` to be `$(this).val()`

Comment: You are actually submitting the form which results in a new page load. It would be easier if you submitted the form contents using an Ajax call. The other way would be to include a hidden form field and setting the id of the field with focus there and reset the focus on page load. But I would really recommend the Ajax solution.

Comment: @Dehalion Unfortunately I haven't had any luck working out how to do this from tutorials. I think I would understand it better if someone were to "Ajaxify" a piece of code I create. Would you be up for the challenge? (I could create another question specifically addressing it and linking it to you?)

Comment: I have now updated the code to reflect my latest efforts. I am attempting to store the ID in a cookie and then focusing on the cookie. However that doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: `$.cookie()` returns the cookie value, you have to create a jQuery object to use `focus()` like this: `$($.cookie("inputFocus")).focus()`. What errors do you get in the JS console or does nothing happen at all?

Comment: I am getting the following error: "Uncaught TypeError: Object function ( selector, context ) {
  // The jQuery object is actually just the init constructor 'enhanced'
  return new jQuery.fn.init( selector, context, rootjQuery );
 } has no method 'cookie'"

Comment: Do you have the jQuery cookie plugin from http://plugins.jquery.com/cookie/ and is it loaded before you use it?

Comment: Ah. That I don't. Doesn't jQuery have cookies built in?

Comment: @Dehalion You have solved it! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to the above problem was to create an object to use focus() and to add the jQquery cookie plug-in.

The change is below:
"$.cookie("inputFocus").focus();" to "$($.cookie("inputFocus")).focus()"

Added the below code to the page:
""